Trouble accessing installation parameters in Contentful app
I need to call the links_to_entry endpoint in a custom app in Contentful, which only exists on the preview API (useCMA hook cannot be used to do this).
AFAIK this means I need to set an installation parameter in the app definition to make the preview API key accessible in the app, making it possible to make the relevant fetch request.
However when I set the key value pair in the app definition and then try to access it in the Page location app via
sdk.parameters.installation, the object is undefined.
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app, seeing if the parameters are available in other locations, but have had no luck.
Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?
